# DBeaver export to csv: "No database selected"

Tags: mysql, mariadb, dbeaver

```
select * from users u
where u.id < 1000
```

When I right-click to script, and export I get **no database selected** error.

When I add "**use db**" command at above,I get a syntax error.

```
use db
select * from users u
where u.id < 1000
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM..'

How do I export in DBeaver?
I use a MacOS, and db is using MariaDB if that matters.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411783).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on your comment I understand now this is a usage question about DBeaver.  You simply need to make sure to select your database in the menu bar above the script tab as outlined here: https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/SQL-Editor/.  See below screenshots for example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Either you have to separate multiple statements by a semicolon (1) or you can pass the database name directly to your statement (2):

(1):

```
use db;
select columns from users u ...
```

(2):

```
select columns from db.users u ....
```

Comment: thank you for your response. yes i tried these, there is nothing wrong with my query, i can execute it, but when I try to export I'm getting these errors. I think its DBeaver related.